# Custom query_var rewrite rule being interrupted by 'page' rewrite rule

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, routes

I have a custom rewrite rule that appears to be getting interrupted.

**The Code:**

```
class drinks {

    public function drink_rewrite_rule() {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'drinks/([a-z]+)[/]?$',
            'index.php?pagename=drinks&drink=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
    }

    public function query_drink($urlslug) {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'drink_data'; // Replace 'custom_pages' with your actual table name
        $slug = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT slug FROM $table_name WHERE slug = %s", $urlslug ) );
        return $slug;
    }
}

$init = new drinks();

add_action('init', [$init, 'drink_rewrite_rule']);

add_filter('query_vars', function ( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'drink';
    return $query_vars;
} );

function test() {
    $slug = get_query_var( 'drink' );
    $clean_slug = sanitize_title($slug);
    $class = new drinks();
    
    if ( get_query_var( 'drink' ) ==  false || get_query_var( 'drink' ) == '' ) {
        return $template;
    }
    
    if ( !$class->query_drink($clean_slug)) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
    }

    return get_template_directory() . '/resources/page-templates/' . 'drink.php';
}
add_action( 'template_include', 'test');
```

**The Problem**

If I use the url `/drinks/coca-cola` the desired outcome occurs:

*Matched Rule*
drinks/([a-z]+)[/]?$

*Matched Query*
pagename=drink
&drink=coca-cola

*Query String*
pagename=drinks
&drink=coca-cola

I then get the template page desired and can utilize the database query to dynamically populate data.

However, if I use the url `/drinks/gg4` the result is:

*Matched Rule*
(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$

*Matched Query*
pagename=drinks%2Fgg4
&page=

*Query String*
pagename=drinks%2Fgg4

The query doesn't even get passed, as Query Monitor shows

```
SELECT slug
FROM wp_drink_data
WHERE slug = ''
```

It is as though, for what appears to be a random reason, something is interrupting this query for some drink slugs and not others. I can enter a random name that isn't even in the database as the slug, and it will at least query the DB.

What am I getting wrong here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
As always with programming, sometimes it is the most ridiculous thing that was overlooked.

The issue lied in my rewrite rule.

`'drinks/([a-z]+)[/]?$'` didn't allow for numeric characters nor dashes, which was why `gg4` wasn't catching.

Changing the rule to the following solves the issue.
`drinks/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$`